# as and as per differences

Tags: prepositions

> 1. **As you** mentioned above mail, I will send you the money.
> 2. **As per** mentioned above mail, I will send you the money.

Which of the above sentence is correct?

Comment: Syntactically, ***as per*** corresponds to *in accordance **with***, which makes your second version non-idiomatic / ungrammatical (since it must be followed by a ***noun***, not a verb form). Your first attempt is also invalid, for other reasons, but note that ELU isn't a proofreading service.

Answer (score 1):

Ambrose Bierce, in *Write It Right* advises against using *per,* for instance, in "Five dollars per day," and that "if you must use the Latin preposition use the Latin noun too: *per diem.*" In your case, "as you mentioned" is fine.